# Why does my CSS not style HTML correctly?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm creating the links for the dropdown menu on a navigation bar using links with icons appearing to the left. Currently I'm able to display the links correctly as links, with icons appearing next to the text, however using the styling code I'm currently unable to change the font size or add padding to the text to add more space between the links.

I've included my code below - please note I'm still very much learning html/css so I'm sure this isn't the best way to do it.

```css
.icon a {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.navbar-item {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/102c5467e4.js"></script>
<a class="navbar-item" href="#about">
  <span>
    <span class="icon"><i class=""></i></span> Accent Chairs
  </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.icon a` targets any `a` element that is a descendant of an element that is a member of the `icon` class.

Your code has one member of the `icon` class and one `a` element but the `a` is an **ancestor** of the `icon`, not a descendant.

Comment: Ah okay, I think I understand. 

In that case, should I either:

1) change .icon a to simply .icon

or 2) add a class to the <span> that surrounds the <span> with icon?

Answer (score 0):

use `a .icon` instead of `.icon a` in your css

```css
a .icon {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.icon::before {
   content: "$"
}

.navbar-item {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/102c5467e4.js"></script>
<a class="navbar-item" href="#about">
  <span>
    <span class="icon"><i class=""></i></span> Accent Chairs
  </span>
</a>
```